# GAS 外部呼出し関数の同時呼び出し

Tags: google-apps-script

GoogleAppsScriptで、ライブラリーを作成し、スプレッドシートから呼び出して処理をした場合、ある関数に対し、たまたま同時に呼び出しが重なった場合どうなるんでしょうか？

- プロジェクトAにて `CmoFunc.掛け算(2,3)`
- プロジェクトBにて `CmoFunc.掛け算(4,5)`

ライブラリー側（CmoFunc）

```
function 掛け算(a,b){
    let c=a*b;
    return c;
}
```

正しい計算結果になるのか・・・？